# How to get all HTML elements in UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have loaded an `UIWebView` with .rtf file.

Now, I want to get all HTML elements or elements present inside the `UIWebView`. Is there any method available to get it?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to get the element...

```
NSString *javaScript = @"document.getElementById( YOU ID );";
NSString *response = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

Hope that helps...

Comment: what is this in swift?

Answer (score 3):

You can get all of the `HTML` content of your `UIWebView` with the call:

```
NSString *yourHTMLSourceCodeString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

After this it's up to you.

Comment: i have similar problem but i need to fetch the only tags whose text are seen in web view. means tags -> h1,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5 are loaded in the webview but in first screen only h1,p1,p2 are seen. then how to fetch that three only ? just like in obove "outerHTML" will gives all html content. if i write "innerHTML" then it will give just body part. then what to write that gives only that tags that are visible in web view. my whole html content load at a time in web view and cut and seen by (pageScroll(%f)). so how to find it ? any idea ?