# Webkit to find elements with Swift

Tags: swift, webkit, ui-automation

I need to test UI in mac OS **(not IOS)** using Swift. I have opened a browser by using Webkit module's `NSWorkspace.shared().open`. Now is there a way to find elements on browser **(Example: find elements by id, click a button etc)** using Webkit.

**Note:** I can't use UIKit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19096986/5362750 i think its helpful